# How do people blank out their answers after they delete them?

Tags: support, deleted-posts

I often see answers that have been deleted and the original author appears to have removed the content after they deleted.  If I try to do this it says I need to enter at least 30 characters and it does not count spaces.

How are they doing this?  Does it just appear empty to other users once it's been deleted or something?

Comment: At the peril of stating the obvious, vandalizing your contributions is not welcome, and a violation of site policy. Users with enough reputation are empowered and encouraged to revert any such edits.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Comment: ​​​​‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​​

Answer (score 10):

You can use HTML comments to overcome the minimum post length restriction:

```
<!-- this text will not appear in the formatted answer -->
```

These comments are ignored by the Markdown renderer.

In general, if you want to see how anybody accomplished anything using markdown, you can <kbd>Shift+Click</kbd> the "edit" link and use the "Rev" drop down at the top to see the markdown source for any revision of the post.  Then merely close the window without saving.

Comment: Alternate method: go to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/[post number here]/revisions` and click any __View source__ link. Of course, this is a pain to remember if the post has never been edited and there's no "edited __x time units ago__" auto-link for that revisions page.